# First amchart not rendering

Tags: amcharts

What does this fiddle for amcharts not render?

http://jsfiddle.net/8ecF7/

```
var dr_data = [{
    "date": "2014-04-01",
    "value": 50
}, {
    "date": "2014-04-02",
    "value": 63
}, {...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you messed things up in css. First, you set style  on "chartdiv" and your div is "chart", and you have an extra } in the middle of css, which makes width and height ignored. It should be:

```
#chart {
    width : 100%;
    height : 500px;
    font-size : 11px;
}
```